# Not able to change div display property using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change display property of my div using js but it is not showing any change.

In Js code if statements are not becoming true though in css all the properties are set properly.
Please help I am a novice and not understanding the issue. Below is the code I am trying

My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="main.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <nav id="nav">
      <ul class="main_nav">
    <li id="About_me"><a href="#" onclick="About_Me_Sel()">About Me</a></li>
    <li id="home1"><a href="#" onclick="Home_Sel()">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div id="About">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="home">
<p>hi</p>
</div>
</body>
```

My JS code:

```
function About_Me_Sel()
{
    var Id;
    Id =document.getElementById("About");
    if(Id.style.display == "block")
    {
    Id.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function Home_Sel()
{
var Id;
Id= document.getElementById("home");

if(Id.style.display == "none")
{Id.style.display = "block";
}
else
alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: You have two different elements with the id 'home'

Answer (score 3):

That won't work the first time around. The style property is not connected to your stylesheet, so JavaScript doesn't know what rule's you've set there. The style property reflects a style attribute that gets written into your element's tag. (You can hard-code one into your HTML if you want.) So the value is always null until you set it.

**Before**

```
<div id="About">
```

**After**

```
<div id="About" style="display: block">
```

---

Try reversing the conditional

```
if (Id.style.display != "block")
{
    Id.style.display = "block";
}
else
{
    Id.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Ajax to load in other content into my div, and i got the content from other php files. this way

```
function changecontent(name){

var htmlUrl = name;
$.ajax({
    url: htmlUrl,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {


        console.log("Current page is: " + htmlUrl);


        $("#maincontent").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).html(data).fadeIn("fast");
        });
    }
  });
 }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="main.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
   </head>
      <body>
         <nav id="nav">
          <ul class="main_nav">
            <li id="About_me"><a href="#" onclick="changecontent("about_me.php")">About Me</a></li>
            <li id="home"><a href="#" onclick="changecontent("home_sel.php")">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
         </nav>
         <div id="maincontent">
              <p>Hello</p>
         </div>
        <div id="home">
      <p>hi</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

eks: about_me.php

```
<a>I'awesome</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of errors in your code; I'll try to go through them one-by-one to clarify those problems and offer solutions that should, hopefully, lead to better understanding (and practice) in future.

First, an `id` "...assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document."<sup>1</sup>. Note the 'must,' which means that a document with a duplicated `id` (more than one element *sharing the same* `id` value makes the document invalid, and causes problems with JavaScript, since it will only *ever* look for *one* element with a given `id`, and recover from invalid documents with unpredictable results).

That being the case I've amended the `id`s of the `div` elements by, effectively, adding the `Content` string, and amended the `id`s of the `li` elements to be single word and lower-case so that they can be predictably made to reference each other. This gives the following HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul class="main_nav">
        <li id="about"><a href="#" onclick="About_Me_Sel()">About Me</a></li>
        <li id="home"><a href="#" onclick="Home_Sel()">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="aboutContent">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="homeContent">
    <p>hi</p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pvJhM/) (this still doesn't work as you'd intend, because the *other* problems still exist; it's merely to show the corrected/amended HTML).

Now, the JavaScript.

The reason it *can't* work, as noted by @Jeffman in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18324547/82548) is because `element.style` references only the in-line styles of an element (those set with the `style` attribute), not the styles set with either a stylesheet or in the head of the document. This means you're comparing an `undefined` variable with a string, which will always be `false`.

You're *also* using two functions to do the same thing, which is wasteful and unnecessary. This is the second reason I've modified the `id`s of the various elements. A modified (single) function to do what you want to do:

```
function sel(e, self) {
    // e is the click event,
    // self is the 'this' DOM node
    var id = self.parentNode.id,
        toggle = document.getElementById(id + 'Content'),
        display = toggle.style.display;
    toggle.style.display = display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

The above requires the following HTML for the `a` elements:

```
<a href="#" onclick="sel(event, this)">About Me</a>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pvJhM/2/).

Now, this *still* requires obtrusive JavaScript (using in-line event-handling within the HTML itself, which requires updates every time you may want to add further event-handling or change the function to call upon those events). Therefore I'd suggest moving to a more unobtrusive version, such as:

```
function sel(e, self) {
    // e is the click event,
    // self is the 'this' DOM node
    var id = self.parentNode.id,
        toggle = document.getElementById(id + 'Content'),
        display = toggle.style.display;
    toggle.style.display = display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}

var links = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function (e){
        sel(e, this);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pvJhM/3/).

Now, while this works, this still requires assigning event-handlers to multiple elements (despite being more easily done using a loop within JavaScript itself).

The easier way is to delegate the event-handling to the parent element, and assess, in the function itself, where the event originated. Which would give the following JavaScript:

```
function sel(e) {
    // e is the click event,
    // self is the 'this' DOM node
    var self = e.target,
        id = self.parentNode.id,
        toggle = document.getElementById(id + 'Content'),
        display = toggle.style.display;
    toggle.style.display = display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}

var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
nav.addEventListener('click', sel);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pvJhM/4/).

---

Notes:

1. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2.

References:

- [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).
- [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).